# ant SQL task fails when calling stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ant, db2

I am attempting to call the following ANT task

```
<target name="sqlcall" description="SQLGETTYPEINFO">
<sql 
    classpath="${sql.classpath}"
    driver="${sql.driver}"
    url="${sql.url}"
    userid="${user.name}"
    password="${sql.password}"
    print="true"
>
CALL SYSIBM.SQLGETTYPEINFO(1,'');
</sql>
</target>
```

but ANT is throwing an exception

```
build.xml:69: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: 
[jcc][10413][10940][3.63.75] Literal replacement parsing failed for procedure call to DB2 for z/OS. 
Failing SQL text CALL SYSIBM.SQLGETTYPEINFO(1,''). 
ERRORCODE=-4463, SQLSTATE=42601 at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:679)
   . . .
```

I know the root cause is that this needs to use the CallableStatement form. Unfortunately, this is not exposed by the SQL task. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I ended up creating a custom task: `public class SqlCall extends JDBCTask {}`

Comment: Bug has existed since 2005:  https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34777